# Was tele-porting mentioned in ancient indian scriptures?

Tags: puranas, upanishads

As shown in various TV shows and movies, was teleporting done as per ancient scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Teleportation, or "Praapti" is one of the eight primary siddhis, or mystic perfections attained by rishis. Through Praapti, they can be transported to the place they desire.

Refer:
http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/15/4-5
http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/15/6-7

Comment: Prapti is about acquisition of objects.  I think mano-javaḥ in verse 6 is more like teleportation.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that! Yes, Manojavah does seem more likely. Though I based my answer on the word Praapti, which is derived from 'Praap' which is used mostly in contexts of moving from place to place, like, "Praapya Dugdhodadheh tatam" means "Having reached the Ocean of Milk".

Comment: Also, since Prakamya is the siddhi for obtaining desired objects, Prapti can be used to denote desired destinations or desired places.